# Font Awesome fonts download issue

Tags: angular, font-awesome, primeng

I am working on UI application with spring MVC as a backend (on Websphere). This application uses Prime NG library to develop User Interface(UI).

The Font awesome has .eot file which contain the images to be display in UI, generally we deploy this .eot file in ear as a static content after doing ng build when we load our application in IE,  the IE try to download those files in temporary internet files so that images can display in UI.

But with my current IE version(IE 11, windows 7) we see that those files are not getting downloaded and due to which no images getting display on UI. If we see IE developer tool we can see IE tried to download file and status of that call GET is successful (200) but none file gets downloaded and download bytes also not as per file size (though the response header content length shows correct length). If I deploy same ear on local WebSphere and access UI with IE it does work.

The same server if we connect with different IE version(IE 11 but latest minor version) using Windows 10 it works.

I think there is some connection configuration which is not going well with particular IE version and some servers. Non of the eot file gets downloaded, I see primeicon.eot is also not able to download.

Please let us know if anyone encounter this issue, also please let us know any alternate ways to include font awesome without .eot file.

I tried to add fountawesome.min.css in index.html, but internally browser again try to download the .eot file.

Answer (score 0):

maybe conflicts in primeNg and fontawesome is  because the ^7.0.0 primeng can use yours own icons

Add PrimeNG and PrimeIcons as a dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
  //...
  "primeng": "^7.0.0",
  "primeicons": "^1.0.0"
},
```

Configure required styles at the styles section.

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
  "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
  //...
```

],

Comment: The same setup works fine on local Websphere, only if we deploy on remote Websphere it fails, only difference is both get call, is one is http and another is https.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to **Press Ctrl + F5** on both systems? Just to be sure that one system is not simply displaying your icons from cache and you have a general issue on ALL clients.

Usually fontawesome has some flaws in interoperability on stacking icons and it looks abit mixed up in some IE versions.

Comment: Every thing mentioned by you tried but still no success.

Comment: Any Adblockers installed or content types not allowed on one systems browser?